# how to bind kendo pivot grid to the sharepoint list by rest

Tags: reports, kendo

i have many lists in sharepoint that gather information from another lists by lookup fields.

we want to make a report by kendo pivot grid.

we have more that 30 reports that connected to lists and show data in *kendo grid*. but this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/pivotgrid/overview) has a complex things about kendo **pivot** grid.

first question is i cant find this dll : http://demos.telerik.com/olap/msmdpump.dll

and don't know how can i host this dll in my IIS or sharepoint and i dont know what is the best way to use it safe?

next problem is that my datasource is not in SSAS - sql server and i have lists.

```
dataSource: {
                    type: "xmla", //define the type
                    columns: [{ name: "[Date].[Calendar]" }], //specify a dimesion on columns
                    rows: [{ name: "[Product].[Category]" }], //specify a dimesion on rows
                    measures: ["[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]"], //specify a measure to display
                    transport: {
                        connection: {
                            catalog: "Adventure Works DW 2008R2", //specify the name of the catalog
                            cube: "Adventure Works" //specify the name of the cube
                        },
```

in other try i can make synced sql server table in my DBs and i have tools that return json from sql but cant make pivot simple sample by this component.

we have many javascript componrents like amcharts and Highcharts that use them and create many reports very easy in my SharePoint portal.

is there any online sample that connected to SharePoint? one clear sample better that 10 articles. :)